# How to save history using QuickBlox android sdk 1.2 version

Tags: android

I am developing a chat application. I have done all the things and I am able to do chat also. But now the problem is that my application doesn't show chat history if I stop the app from background.

Which means If I stop the app and start it again, it doesn't show me the chat history.

Comment: refer this, https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk

Comment: Are you saving chat in history?

Comment: Actually I am not getting the method QBChatMessage in sdk 1.2.2 version. But this method is given under version 2.0. So my question is how would I save my history using this prior version of quickblox. Below is the method wherein I have to use the history funcationality: